# Convert function to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

So I'm new to codeigniter and MVC in general. I have an app that I am converting over and I was wondering what the best way would be to handle this type of function, specifically within the view.

I have a table of categories, that looks like the table below:

```
cat_id | parent_id | catname
------------------------------
1       0           this category
2       1           that category
```

The function, given a cat_id, spits out a formatted string complete with links. I know I shouldn't be handling the URL items until the view, so I am not sure if I rewrite this in CI how to handle the resulting array in the view.

Thoughts? Original function below:

```
    function createPath($id, $category_tbl, $except = null) {
    $s = "SELECT * FROM ".$category_tbl." WHERE cat_id = $id";
    $r = mysql_query($s);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    if($row['parent_id'] == 0) {
        $name = $row['catname'];
        if(!empty($except) && $except == $row['cat_id']) {
            return "<a href='index.php'>Admin</a> &raquo; ".$name."";
        }
        //return "<a href='index.php'>Admin</a> &raquo; <a href='index.php?folder_id=$id'>".$name."</a> &raquo; ";
        return "<a href='category.php?catid=$id&category=".$row['slugname']."'>".$name."</a> &raquo; ";
    } else {
        if(!empty($except) && $except == $row['cat_id']) {
            $name = $row['catname'];
            return createPath($row['parent_id'],$category_tbl, false). " $name";
        } 
        $name = $row['catname'];
        return createPath($row['parent_id'],$category_tbl, false). " <a href='category.php?catid=$id&category=".$row['slugname']."'>".$name."</a> &raquo;";
    }
}
```

Comment: Basic MVC structure is getting as much logic and data fetching out of the view. So you should take out the DB fetching and put it into a model, then take the html out of the function and into a view, then let the controller handle the function call...

Answer (score 2):

Do it in codeingiter framework way..........

1. Write your query function in model
2. Then in controller function call your model and save the result set in an array
3. Then pass that saved array to view
4. In view you parse that array and show how ever you want

   Public function abc(arguments list)

   {

   ```
    $xyz=$this->model->function_name_in_model(arguemnts);
    $model=array();
    $model['content']=$xyz;
    $this->load->view('view_file_name',$model);
   ```

   }

write model function in model page and use passed array in view file.......

Controller................

```
public function createpath($id)

{
   $result = $this->model->getResult($id);

   $model = array();
   $model['content'] = $result;
   $this->load->view('view_file_name_path',$model);

}
```

Model...................

```
public function getResult($id) 

{
   $query_str="SELECT * FROM ".$category_tbl." WHERE cat_id = $id";

    //echo $query_str;exit;
    $res=$this->db->query($query_str);
    if($res->num_rows()>0){
        return $res->result("array");
    }

    return array();

}
```

View file...........................replace $row with $content in your code in view file i assume your code doesn't have errors

```
if($row['parent_id'] == 0) {
    $name = $row['catname'];
    if(!empty($except) && $except == $row['cat_id']) {
        return "<a href='index.php'>Admin</a> &raquo; ".$name."";
    }
    //return "<a href='index.php'>Admin</a> &raquo; <a href='index.php?folder_id=$id'>".$name."</a> &raquo; ";
    return "<a href='category.php?catid=$id&category=".$row['slugname']."'>".$name."</a> &raquo; ";
} else {
    if(!empty($except) && $except == $row['cat_id']) {
        $name = $row['catname'];
        return createPath($row['parent_id'],$category_tbl, false). " $name";
    } 
    $name = $row['catname'];
    return createPath($row['parent_id'],$category_tbl, false). " <a href='category.php?catid=$id&category=".$row['slugname']."'>".$name."</a> &raquo;";
}
```

Comment: The other part of this that I didn't explain properly was what I needed this for. I also have an 'items' table and each item has a 'cat_id' field. When I query the items table, in the view I want to display the category path. So is it best to grab the items in a model, and then go through the items results and add an array to each result of the category data or should I do this in the controller?

Comment: what ever you want to pull how many queries you want to use write functions like how i showed above for each query. And get an array from that functions in controller and pass that to model array in  controller then use those array how ever you want in view file using php, html and css...................

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of quickly (and I mean *quickly*) converting your function to a library.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Path {

    function __construct()
    {
        $_CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function create($id, $category_tbl, $except = NULL)
    {
        $_CI->db->from($category_tbl);
        $_CI->db->where('cat_id', $id);
        $query = $_CI->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $query->row();

            if($row->parent_id == 0)
            {
                $name = $row->catname;

                if(!empty($except) && $except == $row->cat_id) {
                    return "<a href='index.php'>Admin</a> &raquo; ".$name."";
                }

                return "<a href='category.php?catid=$id&category=".$row->slugname."'>".$name."</a> &raquo; ";
            }
            else
            {
                if(!empty($except) && $except == $row->cat_id) {
                    $name = $row->catname;
                return $this->create($row->parent_id, $category_tbl, FALSE). " $name";
                }

                $name = $row->catname;
                return $this->create($row->parent_id, $category_tbl, FALSE). " <a href='category.php?catid=$id&category=".$row->slugname."'>".$name."</a> &raquo;";
            }

        }

        return NULL;
    }
}

/* End of file Path.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/Path.php */
```

Call this with:

```
$this->load->library('path');
$this->path->create($id, $category_tbl, $except);
```

I didn't test it, so there might be some mistakes in there, but this should get the ball rolling I think?

Comment: Thank you! I was beating myself up trying to avoid embedding html within anything but the view.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't have to avoid HTML in a controller (even though it's usually a good idea). When I have non-controller-specific code, I usually split it up into a library if it needs DB access or use of CI libraries and into a helper if it is simple string manipulation.

Comment: Also missed a `$this->db` call and updated the answer to fix it to `$_CI->db`.

Comment: Not yet, I'm trying to figure out how to call this from within another query. I have an items table I want to query and each item has a category ID. I want to send to the view that array from the library in addition to the id itself.

Comment: That might be another question entirely then.